# Rails rich associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have several rich join models and I was wondering if it was possible or rails convention to have the following:

```
has_many :users through => rich_association_one
has_many :rich_association_one

has_many :users through => rich_accociation_two
has_many :rich_association_two
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it may be possible, but i think you will have to use different aliases - as you seem to expect, i think that calling `has_many :users` twice will bring doom upon your model.

try something like this :

```
has_many :rich_association_one
has_many :association_one_users, 
         :through => :rich_association_one, 
         :class_name => "User"

has_many :rich_association_two
has_many :association_two_users, 
         :through => rich_accociation_two, 
         :class_name => "User"
```

more basic info on `has_many` options is available on [RoR guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference).